# QGIS 3.10.7 Buffering a line by 1m with flat end cap, produces "cracked" buffer

Tags: qgis, line, buffer

I need to buffer a line 1 meter, however when running the buffer tool in QGIS with the end cap style as "flat" I get the result shown below.

What causes this, and how can I fix it?

[image: Buffer with cracks]

Comment: This stems from bends in your line. Try buffering a line with a 45° bend, and you'll see it more clearly.

Comment: more likely to be the join style than the end cap

Comment: Is this a collection of lines or a unique polyline? It seems to be a collection of lines, so it has several end caps, and is fragmented. Try to join into a polyline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented, it seems to be a collection of line and not a polyline. I tried to explain in the image below. The first one has a collection of polylines. You can see that when it is a polyline, the buffer stay connected. And when is another line it has a endpoint/cap.

The second sample is when the buffer is checked the dissolve. It looks like your case.

The third sample is a buffer of a unique polyline.

[image]

To tranform the multiline layer to a single poly line you can do it manually with the `merge` tool in the Advance Digitalization toolbar, or with the function `dissolve` (vetor > geoprocessing > dissolve).